# Build RAID 1 array (non-boot), apparently all data is gone?

Tags: debian, backup, raid

The computer that this is occurring in, has a 40GB boot drive (Debian) and two non-boot drives.

I have two identical 1.5TB drives (one partition on each), and one of them had data on it (other was empty). So I ran 'dd' to clone the one to the other, and then I had two identical drives. I wanted then, to build a software RAID array in Debian, and so I created it with one disk and labeled the other one as 'missing.' Added the second disk, and let it sync. And now, mounting and running 'ls' on the new array, I get:

```
# ls
lost+found
```

Using `fdisk /dev/md0` I get:

```
Disk /dev/md0: 1500.2 GB, 1500164849664 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 366251184 cylinders, total 2930009472 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Now, I don't entirely believe that all my data is "gone" since I never formatted the array, but I am saving my "panic" for tomorrow if nothing can be done.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You're severely lacking of basic understanding what RAID is and how to use it. (Why would ya use fdisk /dev/RAID(?) — it's Linux software RAID, not hardware one). No one can put understanding in your head until you want it. So go and read the manual.

Comment: @poige - using fdisk is supposed to give "doesn't contain a valid partition table" on a software array. I was posting that to show that it was indeed an array of 1.5TB.

Comment: I can look into your issue provided with SSH access, but rather not waste my time guessing what you meant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to say, but it's likely that you've hosed both disks because it looks like you created a filesystem on `md0`.

Just in case, give this a try:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

Then mount each member partition (e.g. `sdb1`, `sdc1`) individually and see if you have your original filesystem on either disk.

I know it's a little late, but the correct procedure is:

0) **BACKUP**

1) **Double check that the backup was successful and data integrity was preserved**

2) Create RAID using empty (or destructible) disk (or partition) + `missing`.  *Data on this disk or partition will be destroyed.*

3) Create file system on new RAID volume.

4) Copy existing files to RAID volume from original disk.

5) Add original disk or partition to RAID volume in place of `missing`.  *Data on original disk or partition will be destroyed.*

Since you had cloned the partitions before hand, in the above steps it wouldn't have mattered which disk you used as the "original" or the "empty".

Comment: Running 'testdisk' and other tools now, but it doesn't look good. I forgot to mention that the power failed while I was building the array at first, which is because it was late at night when I posted this. Either way, my fault if it doesn't work. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use RAID, you would have needed to format the disks for it at the beginning.  You haven't said how you created the RAID array, but if you instantiated it with a disk that already had data on it you've lost the data.

Since you used `ls` on the array somehow (did you mount the entire RAID device as an ext3 partition perhaps?), there is a filesystem on it.  This would not be the case if you didn't format it.

RAID1 (as any RAID level) contains metadata in addition to the mirrored data on the volumes.  Simply having two identical volumes is not sufficient to create a RAID array.

Comment: You don't have to format the disks to use them as RAID members.  They can be raw disks, raw partitions, LVs, partitions will filesystems on them, etc.  Also, simply creating a RAID device does not destroy the disk that's the source of the sync.  (I wasn't sure and just tested it on a couple of `loop` disks -- I created an ext3 filesystem on `loop0`, then created `md0` with `loop1 missing`, and then added `loop0` in place of the missing member.  After letting it sync and then stopping the array, `loop0` was still mountable with my existing data).  `loop0` only got hosed by `mkfs.et3 /dev/md0`.

Comment: If you initialize them as part of a RAID array and do anything at all on the array, it will overwrite things.  If you were doing this with a hardware raid controller, merely creating an array with them will usually overwrite their MBR, but not necessarily format them.